# My method compiles but does not do what I want it to do. I want it to save a file to a specific map but it does not do that

Tags: java

When I run this code it works but it saves the file in '' /Users/alencerimpasic/Dokument/java2015/projekt/ '' instead of '' /Users/alencerimpasic/Dokument/java2015/projekt/Glosforhor ''

```
public static void SparaTillFil(List<Glosförhör> data, String filnamn){
    try {
        String filename = "/Users/alencerimpasic/Dokument/java2015/projekt/Glosforhor/" + filnamn;
        Glosförhör tempGlosförhör = new Glosförhör();
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new  FileWriter(filnamn)));
        int n;
        for (n = 0; n < data.size(); n++) {         
            tempGlosförhör = data.get(n);
            outFile.println(tempGlosförhör.getglosa() + "\n" +   
                            tempGlosförhör.getöversättning() + "\n");
        }
        outFile.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"It failed");
    }
}//SparaTillFil ends

public static void GöraGlosförhör(List<Glosförhör> data, List<String> sl){
    String språk = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Write the language the test will be on."); 
    String temp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Write the ammount of words you're going to use in the test.");
    int antal = Integer.parseInt(temp);
    for(int n = 0; n < antal; n++) {
        String glosa = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Write the word!");
        String översättning = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Write the translation!");
        data.add(new Glosförhör(glosa, översättning));  
    }
    sl.add(språk);
    SparaTillFil(data, språk + ".txt");


}//GöraGlosförhör ends
```

Comment: I changed it to '' new FileWrite(filename)'' but now it says ''It failed'' meaning it failed to save to the file. Im not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Oh my... Can you please make your code [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) ?

Answer (score 1):

Although you create a string `filename`, you don't actually use it. You are using `new  FileWriter(filnamn)` instead of `new  FileWriter(filename)`. I'm assuming

> "/Users/alencerimpasic/Dokument/java2015/projekt/"

is the project root, hence `FileWriter` simply selects that as the directory to save to.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have:

```
PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new  FileWriter(filnamn)))
```

I believe you want:

```
PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new  FileWriter(filename)));
```

This is an example of why very similarly named variables can be a source pf errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new  FileWriter(filnamn)));
```

with

```
PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new  FileWriter(filnamne)));
```